# Loading Textures LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have a texture loader from the asteroids examples for LWJGL. It loads the two textures that I supply it and gives them two different textureIDs but when I bind them and draw them on a cube only one texture shows on the cube while the rest are not drawn.

EDIT: I am using the basic of glBindTexture with GL_TEXTURE_2D no multitexturing

Comment: Be more specific about how you are binding them.  Are you using multitexturing?

Comment: Your code contains an error, if you don't show it we can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind a texture inside of the `glBegin()` / `glEnd()` block. You have to do it before you start.